# Request to subdomain gets 301 response

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have installed an nginx server and I can successfully run three different php apps under SSL mapping each one to a distinct subdomain. I would like to add another one, the difference is this is a React app which compiled is no more and no less than a *static* html website.

These are the steps I performed in order to add the new subdomain:

1. added a new entry to the DNS so that the subdomain points to my server ip;
2. created a new `sub.domain.conf` file for nginx:

```
    server 
    {
        listen 80;

        server_name sub.mydomain.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/sub.mydomain.com.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/sub.mydomain.com.error.log;

        root /var/www/tmp/sub;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$is_args$args
        }
     }
```

3. I made sure that the `/var/www/tmp/sub` is owned by the user associated with nginx
4. as the React app has its own routing mechanism, nginx should always pass what's on the right of the domain, that is what I'm trying to do with that `try_files` rule.

The thing is if I try to connect to the subdomain, I either get a `301` status response or I get redirected to another subdomain under https even though I have temporarily disabled the automatic switch to https.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just in case. Have you reload Nginx? :)
Also check if React app doesn't have its internal redirection. It's often happens with java applications.

Comment: @DenisKot yes, a few times actually. Also stopped and restarted. Nothing changes.

Comment: Do you have HSTS headers on your main domain? If you run `nginx -T` to you see the configuration for the sub domain?

Comment: @RichardSmith it turns out I had a typo in the extension of the config file, therefore nginx was ignoring it. I didn't know about the -T option, thank you! It will come in handy next time I will face an issue like this.